# Best Practice on Naming CSS class selector for a same tag, but different behavior

Tags: css, less

Let's say I have a `<td>` html tag like this:

```
....
<td>Sample Item 1 - Common Item</td>
<td>Sample Item 2 - Important Item</td>
<td>Sample Item 3 - Common Item</td>
....
```

And then for the Important Item I need to (for example) color it in red.
Currently Common Item don't need any style and I don't know whether in the future it will need any style or not.
If I want my .Less file follows the best practice on writing css class, should I create the css class in .Less like this:

```
.item {
    &.item-important {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
....
<td class="item">Sample Item 1 - Common Item</td>
<td class="item item-important">Sample Item 2 - Important Item</td>
<td class="item">Sample Item 3 - Common Item</td>
....
```

**OR** should I only create the css class in .Less like this:

```
.important-item {
    color: red;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
....
<td>Sample Item 1 - Common Item</td>
<td class="important-item">Sample Item 2 - Important Item</td>
<td>Sample Item 3 - Common Item</td>
....
```

I'm a bit confused since in Bootstrap I saw a lot like `btn btn-default`, or like `glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk`. Why they don't just put like `btn-default` or `glyphicon-asterisk`? I can't seem to find a good post explaining the best practice and reasoning for this naming style for css classes.
Any insight would be much appreciated!

**---------------------------- Update ----------------------------**

So I was then reading this documentation http://getbem.com/naming/, and found this:
[image]
Now I'm sure that if I have the style for `item` base class, the best practice is putting:

```
....
<td class="item">Sample Item 1 - Common Item</td>
<td class="item item--important">Sample Item 2 - Important Item</td>
<td class="item">Sample Item 3 - Common Item</td>
....
```

But if I don't have the style for `item` yet, is `<td class="item--important">...</td>` still a bad exercise? I'm also considering YAGNI here..

Comment: You might want to read up on the **BEM** (block-element-modifier) concept of CSS: http://getbem.com/introduction/. Basically, since `important` is a state, your class should be `item--important` :) even though the use of separating characters are different, the end goal is the same. In your example, `btn` has a base/default styles, while `btn-default` extends on the button class.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at the link first

Comment: @Terry I updated my question

Comment: A modifier only modifies the base class: the base class should always be declared. Otherwise this defeats the purpose of using BEM.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, if you want to put your comment as an answer I will accept it as the answer @Terry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of naming the CSS classes as such as known as the [**BEM** nomenclature/method](http://getbem.com/), which is an acronym for **b**lock-**e**lement-**m**odifier. What BEM does is that it advocates for a clear and standardised way of naming your CSS classes, so that you do not get easily confused.

The BEM method is what that inspires the CSS classes you come across. In your question, you mentioned `btn` and `btn-default`. In strict BEM sense, that would be `btn` and `btn--default`, since "default" is a modifier/state. However, different authors and frameworks have different means of separating these terms, so `btn-default` is just as legitimate as `btn--default`—as long as you are consistent throughout your stylesheet.

In this case, `btn` is the **base class** of all button-like elements. It likely contains some base styles (like padding, line-height, positioning). `btn-default` is an extension of the `btn` class, perhaps containing colors for the "default look" of the button (I can imagine authors having a standard call-to-action color for buttons). Declaring `btn-default` itself does not make sense, because it **extends** on or **modifies** the `btn` class, which means it lacks the base styles of what is intended to be a button.

Based on this logic, even when `item` does not have any styles explicitly tied to it, you should still include it in your markup, along side with `item--important`, for example. Using `item--important` itself has no meaning.

If you would indulge me in a rather more verbose example, let's say you have the following layout: you want a `<div>` that spans the full width of a container, and sometimes you wanted it to expand beyond the container, and etc...:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 1.5rem 3rem;
  position: relative;
}


/* Base styles for .content */

.content {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}


/** 
 * Modifier: expand
 * Now, we want to increase the width
 */
.content--expand {
  position: relative;
  left: -3rem;
  width: calc(100% + 6rem);
}

/** 
 * Modifier: important
 * Now, we want to draw attention to this content
 */
 .content--important {
  background-color: #b13131;
  color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="content">I am content, with default styles</div>
  <div class="content content--expand">I am content, with expanded width. Note that I inherit base styles from my `.content` block</div>
  <div class="content--expand">I am expanded width content without using `.content`. Look that I am messed up.</div>
  <div class="content content--important">I am a very important content.</div>
</section>
```

Note that the appearance of one of the `<div>` element is off: that is because it does not have the class `.content`, and therefore fails to inherit the "default" look of the `.content` containers ;)

Comment: I really love this detailed explanation, give me insight about the css naming convention, thanks a ton! :)